# Clearing pivot table in C#

Tags: c#, pivot, relationship

I have a table of assistants to events and a table of tasks that can be performed during the event. Each assistant can perform as many tasks as he wants in the event and that's what my database reflects.

```
Table 1      Table 2         Table 3
----------   -------------   ----------
assistants   assistanttask   tasks
id           assistant_id    id
name         task_id         name
```

I know that in order to attach a task to an assistant I can do something like this: **`assistant.Tasks.Add(task);`**

I also know that to remove one task I can write the following code: **`assistant.Tasks.Remove(task);`**

Now my question is, what about bulk detach? I want to remove all the tasks an assistant has. Something like **`assistant.Tasks.RemoveAll();`** but of course that one does not exist. Is there a super easy way to do it?

Comment: The version I have is 6.2.0, sorry I forgot to say that

Answer (score 0):

If using EF5 or EF6 ,You can use ExecuteCommand,like that

```
using (var context = new DataDb())
{
     var ctx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
     ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [TableName] WHERE Id={0}", Id);
}
```